# How can I prevent users to upload the same product twice in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem: my team is uploading the same product twice without notice. Is there any solution to stop that? Or any plugin I can install to prevent this kind of problem?

There are plugins such as a spreadsheet to delete duplicated products but it doesn’t prevent duplication of the product. Rather than I want to prevent the duplication of product titles...